# Объявить TextView

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть Fragment у него есть лояут файл в котором текст вью. Надо отправить на этот текст вью какой то текст.
Обычно я делал так 
`text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
text.setText("");`
 
но во фрагменте метод  findViewById не работает. Подскажите, как быть?

Comment: ищите свой TextView в той вью, которую вы инфлейтите разметку - `text = (TextView)  view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);`

Comment: Ну вот андроид студио предложило мне исправить на         text = (TextView) text.findViewById(R.id.textView3); после чего оно подчеркнуло его и написало "Недостижимое утверждение"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переопределите метод onCreateView (можете скопировать код ниже). Вместо R.layout.your_layout - укажите свой layout

```
private TextView text;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

    text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: А как получить доступ к text за пределами onCreateView?

Comment: Объявляете его в полях класса, а инициализируете в onCreateView, а дальше дергаете его где он вам нужен (в классе). У меня так и объявлено private TextView text; в полях класса (перед методом onCreateView)

Answer (score -3):

```
TextView text=new TextView(someContext);
text.setText("Anus");
setContentView(text);
```